# Render html content in user defined messages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I have a webpage where user will enter his details and then on click of submit, I am invoking a service through ajax call for saving it in db. Then I capture the response from the service written using java REST webservices and display it in the webpage. I am displaying the message "Details saved successfully".This message is read from a properties file in my java service layer and passed back to the web page. I currently need to change font color to the text being returned.

I tried adding the following `<font color="red">Details saved successfully</font>` to my file data and the same text is passed from service layer. IN the web page I see that the font color is not rendered for the text and that the entire above text with html tags is getting displayed in webpage. I am using `$scope.status=response string` in js page and in html page, I am rendering as `<div id="test">{{status}}</div>`

Is there any way to render the html tag when we pass it as string from properties from service layer to js page. My goal is not to change the existing html code and have the html tag rendered when read from properties file and passed as string from services.

Thanks.

Comment: Well you can intercept the response and make ur own html and add css to it

Answer (score 0):

Letting the user submit data containing HTML that is rendered when displayed can be a security risk. Users can be very creative in the HTML code that they "inject" in your application. There are lot of sites where you may find more information about that vulnerability.

When you need to add some markup, you might look at alternative markup rendering methods, for example BBCode or MarkDown.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look at BBCode and Markdown to have the change done permanently. Is there anyway to achieve this without changing the current code base as stop gap fix?